# Check which (combinations) of parameters are null

Tags: java

Suppose I have 4 variables

```
String a;
String b;
String c;
String d;
```

I want to check if individual variable or combination of variable is not Null and act accordingly.

For example one way to do this is using if-else this way

```
     if(a!=null && b == null && c == null && d == null) { 
          //doSomething }
     else if(a==null && b!= null && c == null && d == null) { 
         //doSomething }
     else if(a==null && b!= null && c == null && d == null) { 
         //doSomething }
     else if(a==null && b== null && c != null && d == null) {
         //doSomething }
      ......
        //Similarly combination of two variables
     if(a!=null && b != null && c == null && d == null) {
         //doSomething }
     else if(a!=null && b== null && c != null && d == null) { 
        //doSomething }
     else if(a!=null && b== null && c == null && d != null) { 
        //doSomething } 
      ......
        //and so on 
        //Similarly combination of three variables
     if(a!=null && b != null && c != null && d == null) {
        //doSomething }
     else if(a!=null && b== null && c != null && d != null) {
        //doSomething }
     else if(a!=null && b== null && c == null && d != null) { 
        //doSomething } 
       ....
```

How to achieve this kind of situation `Switch` even don't accept null
I thought of using queue as it dont allow null values but i need to have a key for the variable so that I can get the value and manipulate something. help will be appreciated

Comment: i'm having a quite similar problem, i'd be glad to get a nice answer...

Comment: Your code does not reflect declared variable names.

Comment: Do you want to `doSomething` only if exactly one of the variables is null, or if any of the variables is null?

Comment: Primitive types (like `int`) will never be null.

Comment: Can you make a review of your sample in order to clarify the question?

Comment: Are you only interested in *how many* variables are null, or does it matter *which* variables are null?

Comment: I want to do something if the conditions is satisfied(means any variable can be null I need to check it and act accordingly)

Comment: Can you check individual variables, rather than all at once.

Comment: I'm interested in which(in the sense variable or combination of variable is null) and act accordingly

Comment: Well then, knowing what doSomething does would help, otherwise you are stuck with the code you have provided.

Comment: @B.J.Smegma that is not the scenario because I need to check the individual as well as any combination of them

Comment: @Sarbong I understand, but your code is good as it gets, unless there is some logic in doSomething which could make it simpler.

Comment: Well @B.J.Smegma do something is like I'll get the values at url i'm reading them and I need to search the database based on that parameters the condition is I dont know which variable will be null and the search can be of any combination of variables Now the thing is I can do it very easily with mysql function like `SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE (id IS NOT NULL AND id = ?) OR ...` But i want to do it in java's perspective

Comment: @Sarbong See Trudbert's answer.

Answer (score 9):

You could build an additional variable to achieve this a with switch statement:

```
int switchvar = 0;

if (a == null) {switchvar += 1;}
if (b == null) {switchvar += 10;}
if (c == null) {switchvar += 100;}
if (d == null) {switchvar += 1000;}
```

and then you can use

```
switch (switchvar) {
   case(1): //only a ==null
 ...
   case(101): //a == null and  c == null
 ....
   case(1011): //a,b,d null 
 ....
   case(1111): // all variables null
 }
```

Comment: This is a very neat idea. I would use `0` for null and `1` for non-null, though.

Comment: Would work too but since he wants to check if its null the condition is true when the value is null and therefore 1=null and 0=not null