# Check which combinations of parameters are null in Java

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am new to Java. I am facing an issue now in which I couldn't find the easiest and cleanest way of solving it.

Suppose I have 3 parameters(string) passed to a function(could be a Hashmap too).I want to check if individual variable or combination of variables is not Null and act accordingly.

For example one way to do this is using if-else this way

```
if(a!=null && b == null && c == null) { 
      //doSomething   
}
 else if(a==null && b!= null && c == null ) { 
     //doSomething 
}
 else if(a==null && b0= null && c != null) { 
     //doSomething 
}
  ......
    //Similarly combination of two variables
 if(a!=null && b != null && c == null) {
     //doSomething 
}
 else if(a!=null && b== null && c != null) { 
    //doSomething
}
 else if(a==null && b!= null && c != null) { 
    //doSomething 
} 
  ......
    //and so on 
    //Similarly combination of three variables
 if(a!=null && b != null && c != null) {
    //doSomething 
}

   ....
```

How to achieve this kind of situation. I found similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25366441/check-which-combinations-of-parameters-are-null), but didn't make the code clean. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: The code you have linked is exactly what I would do. Where is the problem there?

Comment: _I found similar question, but didn't make the code clean_ - Can you be more specific, so that we can adapt it to be "cleaner" ?

Comment: There are in total 8 cases. If the action for each of the 8 cases is a different one than the other 7, then your way is the only way.

Comment: Thanks all. I was looking if there is any possibilities to make it more elegant and clean code. Because I personally felt code smell ;). As everyone said I cant avoid using n conditional statements,  I would like to take @khalid ans as almost correct

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Write these utility  functions and you can compare n terms easily.

```
public static boolean areAllNull(Object... objects) {
     return Stream.of(objects).allMatch(Objects::isNull);
}

public static boolean areAllNotNull(Object... objects) {
     return Stream.of(objects).allMatch(Objects::nonNull);
}
```

you can use these functions for n comparisons.

```
if(areAllNotNull(a) && areAllNull(b,c)) { 
      //doSomething   
}
 else if(areAllNotNull(b) && areAllNull(a,c)) { 
     //doSomething 
}
 else if(areAllNotNull(c) && areAllNull(b,a)) { 
     //doSomething 
}
```

Comment: I like this approach. I would rewrite `isAllNull()` this way:
`
    public static boolean isAllNull(Object... objects) {
        return Stream.of(objects).allMatch(Objects::isNull);
    }`

Comment: Thus now the first method `isNull()` is no more necessary ;-)

Comment: @Benoit yeah now that is no mre needed.

Comment: @KhalidShah Looks more readable. But I still have a question. 
`
`if(isAllNotNull(a) && isAllNull(b,c)) { 
      //doSomething   
}
 else if(isAllNotNull(b) && isAllNull(a,c)) { 
     //doSomething 
}
 else if(isAllNotNull(c) && isAllNull(b,a)) { 
     //doSomething 
}`
`
This will handle only 3 cases right? Still we need like n if cases to handle all conditions?

Comment: @AdrinJohnson for n cases you have to write n conditions. but if you have to compare  n variables It simplifies in only two checks like `if(isAllNotNull(k variables) && isAllNull(n-k variaables)`

Comment: @KhalidShah But there is no options to reduce the conditions right?.

Comment: @AdrinJohnson yeah seems not. :)

Comment: well in that case i guess no other possible way to reduce the number of lines of code and make it more readable. I ll accept yours are right ans. Thanks all for the help

Comment: Just one more question. what if the string is not only null. like an empty string
        `String a;
        String b =null;
        String c="";
        String d= "    ";`

Comment: @AdrinJohnson  then you have to make one more fuction isAllEmpty and in which you will check String::isEmpty like function where we use Object::isNull function. And call this function in same manner.

Comment: Ok Thanks Khalid

Answer (score 3):

This is my solution. Note, that you have multiple `if...else` in one single method. And then you add `doSomething`. This is going to be terrible to ready and later to realize.

What about to move one single condition into separate method and name it with relative name. Then, lets encapsulate it into `Consumer` and all of it into a predefined list. Later, if your `doSomething` will be huge, then you can move from single method to single class, not modifying client code.

This is class, to collect required variable for conditions:

```
final class Data {

    private final String a;
    private final String b;
    private final String c;
}
```

Then define one `Consumer` per on `if` statement:

```
Consumer<Data> wonderfulConsumer = data -> {
    if (a != null && b == null && c == null) {
        // do something for wonderful consumer
    }
};

Consumer<Data> badLuckConsumer = data -> {
    if (a == null && b != null && c == null) {
        // do something for bad luck consumer
    }
};
```

**Note,** all these consumers could be modified separately (even be in the different classes).

Then in the client code, define list of all known consumers: `List<Consumer<Data>> consumers = Arrays.asList(wonderfulConsumer, badLuckConsumer)`.

And finally your method will be like this and you do not need to change it when you decide to modify or add consumers.

```
Data data = new Data(a, b, c);
consumers.forEach(consumer -> consumer.accept(data));
```

Comment: If we add another variable to the class ``Data``, we have to modify all the consumers accordingly right?

Comment: @HarshaJayamanna in this example - yes, but you can move condition to the `Data` class itself.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to do this , i will do it in the same way that you have done. 
but if you dont like that and if you think it is not readable you can do it in this way, i expect lot of negative comments to this answer because this is a bad solution.

```
 public static void yourMethod(Object a,Object b,Object c)
  {
    int evaluation = howManyNotNull(a,b,c);

    if(evaluation == 0) // all are nulls
    {
      // your code
    }
    else if(evaluation == 1) // only one is not null
    {
      if(a!=null)
      {

      }
      else if(b!=null)
      {

      }
      else
      {
        // c not null
      }
    }
    else if(evaluation == 2) // two variables are not null but other one is null
    {
      if(a==null)
      {

      }
      else if(b == null)
      {

      }
      else
      {
        // c is null, a and b not null
      }
    }
    else 
    {
      // all abc not null
    }

  }

  private static int howManyNotNull(Object a, Object b, Object c)
  {
    return (a==null?0:1) + (b==null?0:1) + (c==null?0:1);
  }
```

There is extended version of this , assign 3 prime values for a, b , c (example :a=2,b=3,c=5), then use a supportive method like this

```
private static int convertAvailabilityToInt(Object a, Object b, Object c)
  {
    return (a==null?1:2) * (b==null?1:3) * (c==null?1:5);
  }
```

if the answer is 1 ,then all are not null .

Comment: Thank you for the reply. This looks almost similar to my concept. Still thank you for the time

Answer (score -1):

You can use for example a 3 digit string simulating 3 flags.
You first set it to "000".
Then you check each variable for null, if it is not you will replace the 0 with 1.
Then you could use switch cases to treat each case.

Comment: This is exactly the same as the question to which the OP links, since he mentions this did NOT work I would say this is not a valid answer

Comment: It didn't say that is doesn't work. I consider it a cleaner solution still.

Comment: I agree with you that it is a cleaner solution, but IF the OP would see this as a valid answer this question would be a duplicate and the answer is obsolete

Comment: There it was suggested to use some sum approach, I just came with a more cleaner idea of using only the string flag.

Comment: I already found this solution in the link I referenced. But I was just checking out if other possiblities which make more elegant code. Still thank you for your time and effort

Answer (score -2):

You are doing everything right but you have to remember that primitive data types cannot be null. For example string is not null, but empty string "", or int cannot be null, its by default sets to 0. In conclusion Objects like `Map` , `ArrayList` or `Integer`.. you can check for null, but primitive data types cannot be null, so you cannot check them for it. For deeper understanding just learn about primitive and advanced data types.
I hope I got your problem right :)

Comment: who said that variables have primitive data type ?

Comment: String is NOT a primitive in java, so it can be null

Comment: String is not a primitive type and a string can be null

Comment: well it doesnt solve the problem. But thank you for your time and consideration